# Circumvent observable delegate

Tags: delegates, kotlin, observable

Is it possible to circumvent the observable delegate in certain cases?

Use case:

```
val ls: ArrayList<SomeType> by Delegates.observable(arrayListOf()) {
    _, _, new ->
    if (someCondition) {
        usesList(new)
        // I want to reset ls to arrayListOf(), but without the invocation of the observable delegate.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure... You have to have kotlin-reflect in your classpath though. And I would not recommend to use this anyway. :)

```
val delegatedProperties = D::class.java.getDeclaredField("\$\$delegatedProperties").get(d) as Array<KProperty<*>>
(delegatedProperties.find { it.name == "ls" } as KMutableProperty<*>).setter.call(arrayListOf<Any>())
```

Comment: Do you think it's possible without using reflection? I should mention that the only change to ls, is adding elements to it. not changing the elements already contained in ls.

Comment: @SimonMarynissen no, I believe delegates are meant to be invoked every time. It's up to Delegate to decide what to do with each invocation. Or you can create your own Delegate that will encapsulate your conditional logic.